# Problem with FullTextEntityManager indexing all the tables in the db before deployment of war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate complex search within my code to search through just a class for similarity matches.
To enable me achieve that, I have added FullTextEntityManager to be initialized on startup. Now, my app is made of large entities and records making the indexing process terribly slowing down the deployment of the war file and most times resulting to db connection timeout when connecting from db on a different server.

```
/*I have tried using this approach to see if will stop the indexing upon running the project, but the search algorithm never works thereafter because not results was returned*/
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().optimizeAfterPurge(true);


//This is the code doing the indexing of the db records before deployment
 public void initializeHibernateSearch() {

        try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please how can I make the indexing happen only on the entity I am to perform the similiarity match on or rather speed it up to prevent terrible delay of app deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass indexing is not supposed to be performed often: you will need to do it once on your first deployment, and then each time you change your mapping in a backward-incompatible way (adding new fields on existing entities, changing the analyzer on a field, ...). Other deployments do not require reindexing.

So you shouldn't view reindexing as a part of the startup of your application server, but rather as a part of your deployment process. Like you would view, for example, running a resource-intensive SQL script on your database to update your schema.

That being said, yes, mass indexing may be long depending on the amount of data you need to index. It definitely shouldn't result in DB connection timeouts, though. The key is to properly configure reindexing.

In your case, you should take care in particular to limit the number of connections used by the mass indexer. Two settings will come into play: `typesToIndexInParallel` and `threadsToLoadObjects`.

For example:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer()
  .typesToIndexInParallel( 2 )
  .threadsToLoadObjects( 5 )
  .startAndWait();
```

This instructs the mass indexer to index 2 types in parallel, and to use 5 parallel threads to load objects of each type. To that you must add one thread for each type to load the entity IDs. Since each thread needs one connection to the database, this means the mass indexer will use `2 * (5 + 1) = 12` connections.

The default is 1 type in parallel, 6 loading threads, meaning `1 * (6 + 1) = 7` connections.

If you need to use less connections, so that other applications can still access the database, either raise the number of simultaneous connections that the DB accepts to something significantly higher than 7, or configure your mass indexer to use less connections. This means, however, that the mass indexing will take longer.

You will find more information in the [section about Mass Indexing in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer), and [here for JDBC connections in particular](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindexing-threadsandconnections).

Comment: I do not know which technology you use to deploy your war, so I can't answer that. Even if I knew, I'm unlikely to be an expert in that technology. Generally the easiest solution is to set up an administration console in your web application and trigger mass indexing using a button on that console.